# Draw multiple elements from set: overlap

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume I have a finite set of $N$ elements. Now assume that $k$ elements will be drawn randomly from the set (without replacement). These $k$ draws will in total be repeated $I$ times, but between each draw $i\in I$, there is replacement.

How many unique elements $n\in N$ can I expect to draw as a function of $I$, $N$, and $k$ if I assume that each $n$ is equally likely to be chosen? What if each $n$ is not equally likely (because e.g. the likelihood approximates a normal distribution)?

I believe that for the case of equal probability to be chosen, $I\cdot k-\frac{I(I-1)}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)^{2}\cdot k$ should do the trick. Am I right?